# Big-O complexity of java.util.stream.Stream<T>.sorted()

Tags: java, sorting, time-complexity, java-stream

Does anyone know what the time complexity of `java.util.stream.Stream<T>.sorted()` is?

Comment: Well, `Stream` is an interface. It depends solely on the implementation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, `sorted()` in itself is O(1), since it's an intermediate operation that doesn't consume the stream, but simply adds an operation to the pipeline.

Once the stream is consumed by a terminal operation, the sort happens and either

- it doesn't do anything (O(1)) because the stream knows that the elements are already sorted (because they come from a SortedSet, for example)
- or the stream is not parallel, and it delegates to `Arrays.sort()` (O(n log n))
- or the stream is parallel, and it delegates to `Arrays.parallelSort()` (O(n log n))

Answer (score 8):

As of JDK 8, the main sorting algorithm which is also used in standard stream API implementation for sequential sorting is [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). Its worst case is `O(n log n)`, but it works incredibly fast (with `O(n)` and quite small constant) if data is presorted (in forward or reverse direction) or partially presorted (for example, if you concatenate two sorted lists and sort them again).