# How to sort int array efficiently

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have array of ints

```
int array[] = ...
```

and I can sort it using

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

but Arrays.sort uses quicksort, which sometimes result in *O(n^2)* complexity. I had an idea to convert it to List and then sort it (mergesort is used, so upper bound is *O(n log n))*, but the drawback is that it creates a lot of objects due to boxing from int to Integer.

My third approach is this :

```
array = Arrays.stream(array).sorted().toArray();
```

I operate only on IntStream, but unfortunately the complexity isn't mentioned in the documentation.

I was looking for similar questions and I have found only this [Big-O complexity of java.util.stream.Stream<T>.sorted()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301471/big-o-complexity-of-java-util-stream-streamt-sorted)  which isn't helpful at all, because there are two different answers (first is of course partially wrong, because Arrays.sort isn't always *O(n log n))*. What about the second one ? I haven't found the proof.

Comment: From the Javadoc of [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-): "This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations." Your premise is wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP misread the documentation

Comment: @Tunaki His premise is not wrong. The implementation may not exhibit *O(n^2)* behaviour as often as others, but it cannot escape exhibiting it for some datasets.

Comment: Are all those downvotes really necessary?

Comment: @EJP Well yes but saying "Arrays.sort isn't O(n log n)" is wrong.

Comment: @Tunaki Certainly, but that doesn't invalidate the premise of the question.

Comment: Saying Arrays.sort isn't O(n log n) is of course right. Worst case complexity is O(n^2) and having array with 10^6 elements it might not stop for years..

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate [Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), while slightly slower it guarantees O(n Log n). 
[Quicksort vs heapsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467751/quicksort-vs-heapsort)

There is also the textbook explanation [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/).

Answer (score 1):

If the range of integers is small you can use [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), which uses numbers as array-indexes and, unlike comparison-sort algorithms that have a lower bound of O(*nlogn*) (eg Quicksort or Mergesort), it has a complexity of O(*n+k*), where *k* is the range between your min and max value.

Which algorithm to choose always depends on any extra knowledge you may have regarding the distribution of the array elements.

Comment: I know, but range of integers are big,

Answer (score 1):

### O(n) time, O(1) space

Use [`IntArrays.unstableSort(int[] a)`](https://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntArrays.html#unstableSort(int%5B%5D)) from [fastutil](https://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) library.

It uses in-place [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) for big enough arrays and quicksort for small arrays:

```java
if (to - from >= RADIX_SORT_MIN_THRESHOLD) {
  radixSort(a, from, to);
} else {
  quickSort(a, from, to);
}
```

### O(n log(n)) time, O(n) space and Java 14+

> Arrays.sort uses quicksort, which sometimes result in O(n^2) complexity

This is only true if you are using Java 13 or earlier versions. Starting from Java 14 Arrays.sort(int[]) guarantees O(n log(n)) performance in the worst case:

> This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on all data sets, and is typically faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)

This is achieved by [resorting to heapsort](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-14-ga/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java#L961) if recursion becomes too deep:

```java
if ((bits += DELTA) > MAX_RECURSION_DEPTH) {
  heapSort(a, low, high);
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the mergesort yourself, it's no rocket science.
After you have implemented it, do take a little time to run some benchmarks and compare the performance of you implementation with that of `Arrays.sort`. There may be some surprises waiting for you there.

Also, read up on [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), I think you might find the notion useful.

Comment: I have no doubt whatsoever that Don Knuth would be astonished to learn that choosing a sorting algorithm would ever be regarded as 'premature optimization'.

Comment: @EJP you would? Why? Do you think, he would not consider choosing a sorting algorithm "an optimization"? Your surprise can certainly not have anything to do with the other part of the term, as the property of something being "premature" does not depend on the nature of that action, only on the timing of it. 
I am really puzzled. What's your objection here?

Comment: Of course, I can implement it by myself, but I think it is better to first checked if something is implemented. I know about premature optimization, but having array with ~10^6 elements I can't use Arrays.sort, because for some dataset it won't stop for years

Comment: @Pand what makes you think that? Do you have an example of such dataset?

Comment: For now I don't have, but it is possible. It happened to my once in online judge Codeforces where I got time limit, because of using Arrays.sort instead of sorting list. You can read about it for example here : http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7108

Comment: Everything is possible ... Well, almost, anyway. "For now I don't have" is the definition of premature optimization